# Write-Host and Log on one line?

Tags: powershell, write-host

I'm very new to PowerShell, and self-teaching myself it at that.  My question is can you have 'write-host' and 'log-write' on the same line, to run as one action?

What I have is this:

```
Write-Host "Node Id is $nodeProps["NodeID"]" 
LogWrite "Node Id is $nodeProps["NodeID"]"
```

But I'm wondering if there is a way to do it like:

```
Write-Host, LogWrite "Node Id is $nodeProps["NodeID"]"
```

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Assuming Log-write is a function you have written yourself? Could not every call to it also execute a Write-Host on whatever is passed to that function?

Comment: If `LogWrite` is something OP control over, the function could implement passthru: `"Node Id is..." | LogWrite -PassThru | write-Host`

Comment: @campbell.rw  Yes, LogWrite is my own function that took the message I had and appended it to the logfile that had been created earlier in my script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a pipeline with the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet (`%` is its built-in alias) as follows:

```
"Node Id is $($nodeProps["NodeID"])" | % { Write-Host $_; LogWrite $_ }
```

<sup>Note how the reference to `$nodeProps["NodeID"]` needs to be enclosed in `$(...)` to work.</sup>

If you need this repeatedly, define a (simple) function:

```
function writeAndLog([string] $msg) { Write-Host $msg; LogWrite $msg }

writeAndLog "Node Id is $($nodeProps["NodeID"])"
```

---

P.S.: Prompted by [campbell.rw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/380016/campbell-rw)'s comments:

If you don't like the idea of using `ForEach-Object` - which is typically used to *loop* over *multiple* input objects - on a *single* input item, you can use a *script block*, with `&`, the *call operator*:

```
& { Write-Host $args[0]; LogWrite $args[0] } "Node Id is $($nodeProps["NodeID"])"
```

`$args` is the collection of all (unbound) arguments, so `$args[0]` refers to the first one. (In this particular case, just referencing `$args` would have worked too.)

Comment: I'm not sure what the point of the loop is in this answer, which is why I like the other answer better

Comment: @campbell.rw: With a single input object, it's not a _loop_ - the script block (`{ ... }`) is only invoked _once_. The other answer shows how to send the pipeline input to a _file_, which is good to know in general, but not directly related to the question (we don't know what `LogWrite` does; it's quite likely that it's adding metadata to the input message and not just writing to a file, let alone _replacing_ that file instead of _appending_ to it).

Comment: @mklement0 hmm this looks like it may be what I'm looking for!  I'll give this shot and let you know, thanks!

Comment: @mklement Yes it's only invoked once, but looks odd to see a loop when there's no looping going on. How would is be any different than something like &{$d = "message"; Write-host $d; LogWrite $d}

Comment: @campbell.rw: Personally, I prefer the `ForEach` solution, because it doesn't involve a custom variable, but that is a matter of taste. (You could pass a parameter to a script block, but I wouldn't consider that an improvement).

Comment: @mklement0 Fair enough, nothing wrong with personal preference. It's actually interesting a lot of the time to see how others solve the problems!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Tee-Object` cmdlet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object) to copy the pipeline stream to a file:

```
"Node Id is $($nodeProps["NodeID"])" |Tee-Object -FilePath C:\dev\test2.txt -Append |Write-Host
```

Comment: `Tee-Object` is handy in general, but while we don't know what the OP's `LogWrite` does specifically, its name suggests that _replacing_ the log file on every invocation is probably not a good idea, so you should at least add `-Append`.
Beyond that, if `LogWrite` does more than just appending the message to a file (such as adding timestamps), this solution won't work.

Comment: @mklement0 Absolutely true. Append parameter added